# batch file to search in ? and replace it with % in txt file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

i want batch file to search in ? symbol and replace it with % symbol in txt file

i see many of search and replace codes and it is does not replace ? with %

if any one have code and it works on vbs post it

for example:

```
 @echo off     
 setlocal
 set "search=?"                              
 set "replace=%"                              
 set "textfile=test.txt"
 set "newfile=newtest.txt"

 (for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" "%textfile%"') do (
 set "line=%%i"
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
 echo(!line!
 endlocal
 ))>"%newfile%"
 type "%newfile%" > nul
```

Comment: @Mofi - just post this as answer.Though I'm not sure if the OP want a line numbers in the new file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch solution is better than the batch script in question as it does not add line numbers to new file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "search=?"
set "replace=%%"
set "textfile=test.txt"
set "newfile=newtest.txt"
if exist "%newfile%" del "%newfile%"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%textfile%") do (
   set "Line=%%L"
   set "Line=!Line:%search%=%replace%!"
   if not "!Line: =!"=="" echo !Line!>>"%newfile%"
)
endlocal
```

**Attention!**

Blank lines and lines with just spaces in `test.txt` are removed on copying the lines to `newtest.txt` with `?` replaced by `%`. And a line with just horizontal tabs results in getting status of `echo` written into new file. So I recommend to do the replace with a text editor and not with a batch file although I suppose it is possible to improve the code to copy also blank lines and lines with just whitespaces also to new file.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved with the help of powershell, using a single line command, right from command console. See the sample below. If you are planning to use it in batch file, replace % with %%.

```
C:\Scripts>type input.txt
Sometext ? here
here is another ? text
?? test file..
sample??

C:\Scripts>powershell -command (get-content input.txt ^| %{ $_ -replace \"\?\",\"%\"})
Sometext % here
here is another % text
%% test file..
sample%%
```

Cheers, G

Comment: That has to be modified to make it work in a batch file - the `%` need to be doubled to `%%`